# Friday's SMH cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-clues

Try as I do I cannot fit the answers, which I look up on Danword, to any of the cryptic rules that I understand.

So please can someone explain just 3 of the clues/answers

Go through old block - VETO

Articles foremost in most country music - ANTHEM

A tot's raised to adopt Australian philosopher - SPINOZA

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

**VET** is to "go through" in the sense of "process" **+ O** is "old"
=> "block" which is **VETO**

I am not really sure about **ANTHEM**, but it looks like the two "articles" **AN + THE** with the "foremost" part of "most" being **M** => **ANTHEM** which is country music?? (edit: duh as in the music of a country.. sorry I am slow today)

"A tot's" in slang could be **A NIPS** in the sense of "a shot of alcohol"... "raised" being reversed and "adopt" indicating put "Australian" = **OZ** in it for a confusing clue to the philosopher **SPINOZA**

Someone else may have better justification!